# Passing Views to Listview\RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, listview

What am trying to accomplish here is create a listview or recyclerview if you like, to set UI views on the screen instead of using a scrollview, this concept is pretty popular among iOS developers where they create a table view and pass it views in an NSArray. I have done that part so far, problem is the listeners don't work if they are set in the activity before putting them in an arraylist to be passed to the list/recycler, here's my code so far.

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

views = new ArrayList<>();

d = new DatePicker(this);
views.add(d);

e = new TextInputEditText(this);
e.addTextChangedListener(this);
views.add(e);

ee = new TextInputEditText(this);
ee.addTextChangedListener(this);
// views.add(ee);

Button b = new Button(this);
b.setText("hi btn");
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
views.add(b);

Adapter adapter = new Adapter(views, this);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: More than likely, the RecyclerView is "consuming" any click events before they reach the views of the adapter. Besides that, what you are describing is not how an Adapter is meant to be used. LinearLayout + ScrollView is exactly what you need.

Comment: Actually this is not a typical android design pattern. We do not pass the views on Arrays. *I'm not sure if this is recommended in iOS as well*.

Comment: Yeah I know, but this is just a POC to test the idea ...

Comment: Ok,I understand. And the views should be added in your Adapter itself. The use of the array is to represents the dynamic datas its either coming from a web service or local database..

Comment: In the View Holder part you can set the listener there, assuming that you have a context reference in your adapter coming from your activity.

Comment: This question cannot be answered without the adapter code